# How to use mysql.exe from C#

Tags: c#, mysql, cmd

I need to call the following command from C# code:
mysql.exe --user=useranme --password=password --database=base < C:\backups\data.sql

I use:

```
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "mysql.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--user=useranme --password=password --database=base < C:\backups\data.sql";

process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(args.Data);
});

process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();

process.WaitForExit();
```

But it does not work as a direct entry to the command line. I see that the right part "< C:\backups\data.sql" is not executed.

Help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this is because writing < filename at the command prompt force the shell to submit the content of the file c:\backups\data.sql in the *standard input* of your program. Passing the part after the '<' in the argument is not correct because you have to feed the stdin of your executable whith the content of the file.In order to do stdin/stdout redirection you can refer this question:

[Redirecting stdin and stdout where stdin closes first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373387/redirecting-stdin-and-stdout-where-stdin-closes-first)

and you will push the content of your data.sql file onto the stdin stream.

Answer (score 2):

Just something I noticed, could it be that your database is not called `data.sql` but somehow else, where first letter matches some [escape sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)?

You need to escape all `\` characters in path or C# compiler will treat them as escape sequences.
In your code, `"C:\backups"` actually becomes `C:□ackups`.
You either need to prefix string with `@` which tells compiler to not use escape sequences, or else prefix `\` with another `\`:

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"--user=useranme --password=password --database=base < C:\backups\data.sql";

process.StartInfo.Arguments = "--user=useranme --password=password --database=base < C:\\backups\\data.sql";
```

However it is just as possible that you just typed some path here and your code doesn't have this mistake.

Answer (score 1):

See the answer by SchlaWiener here:

[Problem, executing commands in cmd using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035102/problem-executing-commands-in-cmd-using-c)

It worked for me! :)